# How to set value of date field to another date field on submit

Tags: php, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I am using the entityforms module with Drupal 7. I am looking to have the user to fill out a form whereby one of the fields is a scheduled time. I want the user to have the ability to edit this form later and change the scheduled time, but I want to keep the first scheduled time that the user had inputed. I am looking to do that by making another hidden date field and, on submit, the hidden date field is equal to the scheduled time field the user filled out, and on edit, the hidden date field never changes. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can even try for [Track Field Changes](https://www.drupal.org/project/track_field_changes) module. It can provide you with field revisioning. I hope it might help you.